# Streaming Youtube Video in WPF

Tags: c#, audio, youtube, streaming, wmp

I have an application that can play online radios with the Windows Media Player. Now I wanted to add Youtube as a source aswell (videos only). I couldn't really find anything regarding to this. If it does not work with the WMP I am also free for any other ways.

What I tried so far was setting the URL of the WMP to the following values:

1. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID`
2. `https://www.youtube.com/v/ID`

Both of them without any success.

Note: I only need the audio not the video itself.

Comment: try `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` control (embeded IE) or CEF wrappers for C# (eg. CefSharp)(embeded Chromium), running it without display, and call their Javascript interaction APIs to perform the play controls

Comment: So there is not a way to do it for example with ffmpeg/youtube-dl?